# How to reduce mem_fragmentation_ratio in Redis?

Tags: redis

By `info` command, I get

`mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.24`

which is greater than `1`.

I know it means redis hold some free memory which can be released.

How can I release this memory and reduce this ratio?

I tried `MEMORY PURGE`, but the ratio does not change.

`redis_version:4.0.9`

```
# Memory
used_memory:8347302992
used_memory_human:7.77G
used_memory_rss:9236336640
used_memory_rss_human:8.60G
used_memory_peak:17919661152
used_memory_peak_human:16.69G
used_memory_peak_perc:46.58%
used_memory_overhead:519883816
used_memory_startup:1215600
used_memory_dataset:7827419176
used_memory_dataset_perc:93.79%
total_system_memory:270383198208
total_system_memory_human:251.81G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:21474836480
maxmemory_human:20.00G
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.11
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

Comment: How much data is in your server? Note that you usually see high fragmentation rates when the dataset is relatively small. If fragmentation is indeed an issue, you can try enabling active defrag to resolve it.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I added the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is not very good about releasing unused memory. In general, redis will retain all memory it consumes at its peak. This is not usually a problem as long as your server has enough memory to service it. I can see from your info that your server has much more memory than you are actively using for redis.

To be clear, the [`MEMORY PURGE` command](https://redis.io/commands/memory-purge) only works with the jemalloc memory allocator:

> The MEMORY PURGE command attempts to purge dirty pages so these can be reclaimed by the allocator.
>
> This command is currently implemented only when using jemalloc as an allocator, and evaluates to a benign NOOP for all others.

So, if you are running redis on windows or mac, you probably can't use `MEMORY PURGE`.

In general, though, I wouldn't worry about a fragmentation ratio that is so close to 1. Problems generally arise only when the fragmentation ratio goes below 1 or is much higher than 1 (eg- 10 or more).